# Calculate Sum from Multiple Section Table using Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I have a `UITableView` with 2 sections, each getting info that's been added to `Core Data`. Each section has an attribute called amount. I want to get the sum of each section.

Right now my code is giving me the sum of all of the values.

How can I modify it to go through each section?

I am using an `Integer 16` to add values between the two sections.

Here's my code:

```
- (void)calculate {
    CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = coreDataStack.managedObjectContext;

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MyEntityName"];
    fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

    NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
    expressionDescription.name = @"sumOfAmounts";
    expressionDescription.expression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"@sum.amount"];
    expressionDescription.expressionResultType = NSDecimalAttributeType;

    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[expressionDescription];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if (result == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
    else
    {
        NSNumber *sumOfAmounts = [[result objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"sumOfAmounts"];
    }
}
```

SOLUTION:

I added a NSPredicate to my code and was able to get a certain value of my `Integer 16`.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myInt16 == x"]; // x is the value I want to get to (in my case I have 0 and 1)
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: You can post that solution as the answer, and accept it after a few days.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without the `NSExpression` madness and with much better CPU and memory performance by employing a `NSFetchedResultController`.

Set the fetched results controller's `sectionNameKeyPath` to the attribute that distinguishes the two sections, let's call it `section` (which might contain just `0` and `1`).

Then, conveniently calculate the sum in the table view's `titleForHeaderInSection`.

```
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> info = 
   self.fetchedResultsController.sections[section];
NSNumber *sum = [info.objects valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.amount"];
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the `propertiesToGroupBy` for your fetch request:

```
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[@"myInt16", expressionDescription];
fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = @[@"myInt16"];
```

The fetch will return an array of dictionaries, each with two keys: "myInt16" and "sumOfAmount".